# How to display on jquery calendar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using jquery calendar. I want to display list of local holiday's on calendar. I am using below script. Calendar working fine. Only i need to display holidays.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var calendar = $('#notice_calendar');
    $('#notice_calendar').fullCalendar( {
            header: {
                left: 'title',
                right: 'today prev,next'
            }, //defaultView: 'basicWeek',
            editable: false,
            firstDay: 1,
            height: 530,
            droppable: false, 
            events: [ <?php
                $notices    =   $this->db->get('noticeboard')->result_array();
                foreach($notices as $row):
                ?> {
                    title: "<?php  echo $row['notice_title'];?>",
                    start: new Date(<?php echo date('Y',$row['create_timestamp']);?>, <?php echo date('m',$row['create_timestamp'])-1;?>, <?php echo date('d',$row['create_timestamp']);?>),
                    end:    new Date(<?php echo date('Y',$row['create_timestamp']);?>, <?php echo date('m',$row['create_timestamp'])-1;?>, <?php echo date('d',$row['create_timestamp']);?>)
                },
                <?php endforeach ?> 
            ]
        });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: What is the content of `$row['create_timestamp']`? Is it an integer?

Comment: its a long text... is it possible to hard code the holidays and show??

Comment: The second argument in PHP `date()` should be an integer [Reference here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) representing a number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT). So if you have the dates in database, maybe an other approach would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add custom holiday on calendar by using.

**JsFiddle Demo** **[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/marcrazyness/C8jpm/)**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        theme: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultDate: '2014-07-04',
        editable: true,
        events: [{
            title: 'All Day Event',
            start: '2014-07-01'
        }, {
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: '2014-07-07',
            end: '2014-07-10'
        }, {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2014-07-09T16:00:00'
        }, {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2014-07-16T16:00:00'
        }, {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: '2014-07-12T10:30:00',
            end: '2014-07-12T12:30:00'
        }, {
            title: 'Lunch',
            start: '2014-07-12T12:00:00'
        }, {
            title: 'Birthday Party',
            start: '2014-07-13T07:00:00'
        }, {
            title: 'Click for Google',
            url: 'http://google.com/',
            start: '2014-07-28'
        }],
        eventAfterAllRender: function (view) {
    //Use view.intervalStart and view.intervalEnd to find date range of holidays
    //Make ajax call to find holidays in range.
    var fourthOfJuly = moment('2014-07-04','YYYY-MM-DD');
    var holidays = [fourthOfJuly];
    var holidayMoment;
    for(var i = 0; i < holidays.length; i++) {    
     holidayMoment = holidays[i];
     if (view.name == 'month') {
      $("td[data-date=" + holidayMoment.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "]").addClass('holiday');
     } else if (view.name =='agendaWeek') {
      var classNames = $("th:contains(' " + holidayMoment.format('M/D') + "')").attr("class");
      if (classNames != null) {
       var classNamesArray = classNames.split(" ");
       for(var i = 0; i < classNamesArray.length; i++) {
        if(classNamesArray[i].indexOf('fc-col') > -1) {
         $("td." + classNamesArray[i]).addClass('holiday');
         break;
        }
       }
      }
     } else if (view.name == 'agendaDay') {
      if(holidayMoment.format('YYYY-MM-DD') == $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate').format('YYYY-MM-DD')) {
       $("td.fc-col0").addClass('holiday');
      };
     }
    }
   }
    });

});
```

Comment: when run code snippet i am getting an error {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 13,
  "colno": 9
}

Comment: just go to the reference i give on the bottom Click me